# Объединение всей выборки в одном запросе в SQL

Tags: postgresql, sql

Имеется запрос:

```
SELECT array_to_json(ARRAY[param[3],data[1],param[4]]) FROM jf_users;
```

который возвращает:

```
["15dddf","root1","192"]
["b66e08","root2","192"]
["38d414","root3","192"]
```

Возможно ли силами SQL, пропустив его через еще один запрос (например, `SELECT ... FROM (первый запрос) AS sub;`), получить такой результат запроса в одну строку:

```
["15dddf","root1","192"], ["b66e08","root2","192"], ["38d414","root3","192"]
```

Т.е. суть вопроса заключается в основном в том, как перебрать результат запроса и склеить все строки ответа первого запроса в одну строку, добавив между ними какой-то текст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(array_to_json(ARRAY[param[3],data[1],param[4]])),',') FROM jf_users;
```

**Обновление**

Функция array_agg поддерживает сортировку: `array_agg(<выражение> ORDER BY <поле>)`, не знаю, поможет Вам это или нет, ибо не знаком со структурой таблицы.

Comment: Это именно то, что мне было нужно, благодарю!
____________


Кстати, а как в данном запросе делать ORDER BY id? При добавлении в конце ORDER BY id ошибка:

>колонка "jf_users.id" должна фигурировать в предложении GROUP BY или использоваться в агрегатной функции

Comment: Функция array_agg поддерживает сортировку: array_agg(<выражение> ORDER BY <поле>) не знаю поможет Вам это или нет, ибо не знаком со структурой таблицы